# detail not showing up from node editor

Tags: node-editor

Hi I'm following the blender guru intermediate tutorial series and am on part 8 where he textures the anvil i am doing everything that he does but the added detail like the bump map just is not showing up on my mesh[image]

Comment: Welcome, Case-F. The last node is not connected to the Mapping Node.

Comment: what do you mean